# How to change the contents of an imported .py file?

Tags: python

I import a file with a class that has a dictionary. In my program (Tkinter) I display the dictionary's pairs of keys and values (PARENT WINDOW). Additionally, I can press a button to change the value of a key in that dictionary (CHILD WINDOW) through a function written within that imported file. However, no matter what the file is unchanged. I tried to check it in isolation from the main code. Like, basic

```
print(dictionary) -> {"a": "Empty"}
dictionary.change("a", "Emptyness")
print(dictionary) -> {"a": "Emptyness"}
```

This piece executes correctly. But if I run the code again, the value of "a" will again become "Empty". And if I take a look at the imported.py, it will be the same as it was.

So, is there a way to permanently change (and, I think, update) this imported .py file? Or would it be better if I put this dictionary in a .txt, .csv, .json, etc.?

Comment: Do you mean it reverts when your program exits and restarts? That's normal. If the goal is persistent data across runs, you generally don't change the source code, you store it in a data file you rewrite, or in a persistent database of some sort.

Comment: "would it be better if I put this dictionary in a .txt, .cvs, .json, etc.?" Yes, it would. Do not try to edit source code from within the program. If something needs to change between program runs, it is *data*, and that is *exactly the purpose* of such files. (It's `.csv` rather than `.cvs`, by the way.)

Comment: @Karl Knechtel
Ok, thank you. I won't break my head over it any more)